# Select sentences in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to filter a text to keep only the sentences that include at least one word from a list of words.

The script is working but picking some wrong words. For example, my list includes the word "RESULT" and I am picking sentences with the word "RESULTING". Here is the section of the code.

```
    sentences = split_into_sentences(doc)
    for sentence in sentences:
        if any(ele in sentence for ele in keywords):
            sentences_to_write.append(sentence)
```

where sentences is the list of sentences (text) and keywords is the list of keywords.

Comment: look at `split` and `in`. But i mean, there's no effort shown here. Search on SO or online and make an attempt first. what have you tried so far?

Comment: In addition to the comment above, how does your text file look like? Is each sentence separated by a delimiter? Is each line considered a new sentence irrespective of anything? Need more information.

Comment: could you provide some sample dataset?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh sorry for being a bit short in exposing the issue, please see if you can help now. Thanks

Comment: Well it is doing precisely what you asked for :-) "RESULT" is in "RESULTing" (the same as RES would be in RESULTING as well).
As suggested above, you should use `split` to take the single words from sentence and then check if they are in your keywords.